# creating a Field based on the data in choice field in django

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to write a program for registering plates. However we have three types of plate and i've created a choice field for these three. the thing i wanna do is that i need to create a OneToOne field which it's given model is based on the data of the choice filed for example if the user chose 1 i need to have OnetoOne field to CarPlate if 2 OneToOne field to MotorPlate and so on....

```
VEHICLE_CHOICES = (
("1", "سواری ملی"),
("2", "سواری منظقه ازاد انزلی"),
("3", "موتور سیکلت"),)

class Vehicle(models.Model):
vehicle_type = models.CharField(
    max_length=3,
    choices=VEHICLE_CHOICES,
    blank=False
)
# below is an example of what i want to do
if vehicle_type == 1 :
    plate_car = models.OneToOneField(CarPlate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="savari", blank=True)
elif vehicle_type == 2:
    plate_anzali = models.OneToOneField(AnzaliPlate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="mantaqe", blank=True)
else:
    plate_motor = models.OneToOneField(MotorPlate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="motor", blank=True)
```

the code above works but it doesn't give me the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently these kind of settings are not allowed in models, but you can write a global field for every one of them and then in the front-end part of the project you can only get the fields that you want for the chosen choice field